# How to properly handle persistence of data and alert of status in view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, rest, asynchronous, uitextview

I have 2 text views in an iOS app for updating a users password.  I am using a RESTful web service to persist the data to a remote database after a user clicks a confirmation button.

If something goes wrong in transmission or if the input data fails validation on the server side, how do I communicate this to the user?

I don't want to keep the user waiting while this timely process goes on.  I want to make the service asynchronous and alert the user of the status even after they have clicked into another view.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the request delegate to be your UIApplication delegate

In the case of using ASIHTTPRequest, set a userInfo dictionary with your failure message

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:@""];
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Password reset failed" forKey:@"failureAlertMessage"];
[request setDelegate:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
```

Conform your UIApplication delegate to the request delegate protocol (for example, ASIHTTPRequestDelegate)

In the UIApplication delegate, use the information contained in the request to show an error message

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if([[request userInfo] objectForKey:@"failureAlertMessage"]){
        //Do the alert
    }
}
```